# Force rsync to transfer files in the order listed in the from-file param

Tags: cygwin, rsync

Say you have a list of files in `filelist.txt` and call rynsc like so:

```
$rsync --files-from=filelist.txt /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Rsync sorts the files in `filelist.txt` before processing them. According to the `man` page, this is to make the transfer more efficient.

How do I turn that off?  I have a case where I want the files transferred in a very specific order and I don't care if it makes the transfer less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat filelist.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} rsync --progress "/path-from/{}" "/path-to/{}"
```

This should pass each file to rsync via xargs one line at a time.

You can replace

```
cat xxx.txt
```

with

```
ls -t | xargs ....
```

if you prefer.

Indeed rsync annoyingly doesn't use the order that you specified in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like two options:

- Do one at a time.
- Patch `rsync`

Wish there was a better answer. It would take a good look at the source code to reveal exactly what it's doing, but it looks alphabetical.